# adding one more condition in IIF Clause

Tags: coldfusion

I am using the following code for the displaying conditional code:

```
spreadsheetSetCellValue(Newspreadsheet
        , IIF((gop.IssueType NEQ ""),DE('#gop.IssueType#'),DE("#go.pTypes#"))
        , x+1
        , 3
 );
```

I want to add one more condition: where `go.pTypes is not ""`, display `1` else `0`.

Please guide

Comment: Which version of CF?

Comment: No doubt, the reason Adam asks is because he would answer the same way that Henry did answer. Use "Ternary ifs" over IIf if you can. I'd say there's no danger of support for IIf disappearing but they have that nasty DE() situation that's only annoying. `IIF((gop.IssueType NEQ ""),DE('#gop.IssueType#'),DE("#go.pTypes#"))` and `((gop.IssueType NEQ "") ? gop.IssueType : go.pTypes)` produce exactly the same result. Should you be using an old version of CF, just change Henry's answer to IIF(...) format instead.

Comment: spreadsheetSetCellValue means at least CF9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pType = go.pTypes NEQ "" ? 1 : 0;
value = gop.IssueType NEQ "" ? gop.IssueType : pType;

spreadsheetsetcellvalue(Newspreadsheet, value, x+1, 3);
```